# Is it better to use an offset or manually set CPU voltage (with respect to CPU longevitity)?

Tags: cpu, overclocking, voltage

### The Background:

I recently built a new computer, and I'm working with the [ASUS P8Z68-V Pro](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_PRO/) motherboard and [Intel i7 2600k](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52214) processor.  While this question **does not** pertain specifically to *my* hardware, I mention what I have to explain the voltages/temperatures I get.  Do note that the information in your answers should *not* pertain to my specific case, but computer hardware in general.  Furthermore, the information should apply regardless of if the system is under-clocked, stock-clocked, and over-clocked.

---

### The Details:

In my motherboard, there are two options that pertain to my question.  The first is load-line calibration (LLC), and the second is setting the CPU voltage by manual/offset mode.  After some experimenting with my manually set multiplier, I have come up with the following as a stable set of voltages in each voltage mode:

- **Manual Voltage** - 1.19V at idle , drops to 1.18V under load (LLC on high).
- **Offset Voltage** - 0.93V at idle, 1.19V under load, voltage spikes to 1.25V under load transitions (LLC is off).

Now I understand *why* the voltages result from each setting (like [V<sub>droop</sub>](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=107986)), and *why* I need to turn LLC on/off in each case, but there are two sides to the hypothetical coin here.  While my *load* temperatures are about equal in each case, the CPU *idles* a few degrees cooler in offset voltage mode (due to the lower idle voltage).

That being said, in offset mode, I noticed an interesting side effect - load transitioning causes the voltage to spike up to 1.25V.  I also noticed that the voltage stays at 1.25V when starting the computer (until Windows is fully loaded and SpeedStep begins to work... brownie points if you can also tell me why this happens).  With LLC enabled on any setting in offset mode, the load and idle voltages remain the same, but the peak transition voltage gets a *lot* higher (over 1.3V).

Conversely, when I set the voltage to manual mode (with LLC *enabled*, since without it V<sub>droop</sub> causes it to be unstable at idle), the CPU is constantly at ~1.17-1.18V, in both idle/load/startup.  My point is that I don't see *any* voltage spikes between load transitioning - the voltage is almost constant, all the time.

Again, note that in both cases, my load temperatures are the same (a perfectly acceptable 65°C under a stress test, mid to high 50's under normal full load).  Thus, **I am not worried about temperatures (even at idle), but rather the longevity of the CPU with respect to these voltage settings**.

---

### The Question:

For the long-term use and stability of a computer, with respect to CPU degradation and longevity, is it better to use an offset voltage (which results in a lower idle but higher transition voltage) or manual voltage (roughly constant voltage)?  Will the offset voltage spikes (although within my manufacturer's specified voltages) harm the CPU or cause it to degrade faster over time?

Assume the system is under load 60% of the time it is on (which is why I want to use offset mode - cooler and less power at idle).

***Reason for bounty:*** I would appreciate some hard evidence (datasheets, research papers, studies, or *any* proof really) in favour of one method or another, specifically pertaining to fluctuating versus constant voltage.

Comment: Are we talking about an 24/7 system or a regular office desktop on only during office hours?

Comment: This is my personal desktop, and assume it is in use for 12-16 hours per day.  That being said, I don't think the answer should depend on how long the computer is turned on per day (everything should be normalized for how long the computer was turned in *total*, not per day).  Just so you know though, I've ensured that the machine is stable and well within acceptable operating temperatures for loading it 24-hours-a-day.

Comment: Not quite an answer... but I would leave it at stock (including cooler) and expect greatest longevity that way. Overclocking scares me after having eaten 6 months of my life over a bad purchase.

Comment: @PriceChild You couldn't pay me to use a stock cooler.  Overclocked or not, there is not a single advantage to a stock cooler over an aftermarket one.  The stock ones are always  small, cheap, and don't cool nearly as good as most aftermarket solutions.  I'd also like to note that the voltages I listed above are actually *less* then the ones I get when I set everything to `Auto` in my motherboard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both temperature and voltage kills a CPU. A high voltage spike can kill it quickly. In your case I wouldn't worry though. The voltage spikes you have are still low. The Intel spec sheets specify the max <strike>vCore</strike> VID as 1.52v for that processor. Now, I wouldn't actually run the processor at anything near that, but on the other hand I doubt a voltage spike up to that would kill it either.

Faced with the very same question you are posing I went with the offset. I figured the bigger killer would be the extra idle voltage and temperature. And I have a much higher overclock than you do. With the overclock you have I would still expect to get 10 years of life out of the processor either way.

Comment: +1 for referencing the [Intel datasheet](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/datashts/324641.pdf).  Just curious, do you have any sources or references for CPU lifetime expectancy?  With the clock speed I have, I'd say the processor is at stock frequency pretty much - I just want to know if those little voltage blips, even though they are a small magnitude, will do any harm.

Comment: Sorry, and a little FYI - Intel specifies the maximum VID as 1.52V, *not* Vcore.  I just mention this because under load, CPU-Z reports my VID as ~1.34V, but HWMonitor/HWInfo64 reports the CPU core voltage as 1.19V.  If I recall correctly, `Vcore = VID - Vdroop`.

Answer (score 3):

In response to music2myear.

It's not just heat that kills a processor. Breakthrough is correct, the interconnects degrade with increased voltage:

V=IR

If you increase the voltage (while resistance remains constant), the current will increase proportionally. Increased current running through interconnects leads to electromigration which transports conductor material away from the interconnect due to momentum transfer between electrons and metal ions.

From a simplistic point of view you could think of it as a river eroding its path. Basically, if the increased current degrades the interconnects, they will eventually fail. All CPU's have a finite lifetime, but increasing voltage, and hence current will decrease its lifespan.

That said, I recommend offset voltage, it will result in far less current passing through your processor, and the small voltage spikes are of no consequence at 1.25V.

Comment: If the spikes are considerably higher, another phenomenon happens, one much more serious: parts of the silicon which are supposed to be insulators actually start conducting electricity, effectively ["shorting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit) the SoC.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an extension to Mr Alpha's answer, I also found [this interesting guide on [H]ard|Forum](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1578110) in regards to overclocking on the Sandy Bridge chipsets.  In regards to SpeedStep settings:

> It possible to overclock while keeping speedstep enabled and use the
>   offset voltage method for Vcore increase this will provide the overall
>   best in temperature and eatsink performance as well as generally
>   efficiency and extension of the lifespan of the motherboards its
>   components and the CPU. This is due to the Turbo Multiplier working
>   and exucting ramping as Intel intended.  Example leaving all CStates
>   and Speedstep enabled will allow the CPU to idle down in Vcore and
>   frequency (1600MHz) and ramp up when under load to 4.8GHz when
>   needed.

Since I have a modest overclock, and have all power-saving settings enabled (there are no stability or performance issues in doing so), I believe that keeping the CPU voltage in offset mode would be the best choice in this case.

For anyone going down this route as well, do keep an eye on your temperatures and voltages using a temperature monitoring tool (e.g. [HWMontior](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) or [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/)).  Pay special attention to the maximum CPU core voltage, and see if that fits within your needs.  Also note the effects of V<sub>droop</sub> (see my comments on [Mr Alpha's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/309577/is-it-better-to-use-an-offset-or-manually-set-cpu-voltage-with-respect-to-cpu-lo/309698#309698) for details).

Comment: Breakthrough, if you don't mind me asking, did you really not need LLC with this overclock? Ever tested with Prime 95? If yes, no calculation errors returned?

Comment: @Marc.2377 Yes, I am still using the same configuration, albeit with a slightly higher voltage (had to bump it up about once a year due to crashing/Prime95 failures).  I have my setup at 4.0 GHz, just to confirm, not the frequency above I quoted from the article.  I have since moved to an Intel 6700k, and with my motherboard configuration, where I do now use LLC (stock 4.2 GHz clock with undervolted manually set voltage).  I still have to bump the voltage up after several months due to how close it is to the stability level (this is the one disadvantage of using the lowest possible voltage).

Comment: I see. Thanks for letting me know. I did some testing a month ago (you can see in my profile, self-answered question), that's why I was curious. Regards.